# Custom Formula Data Validation

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

Can we set the following data validation rule across a range to prevent duplicate entries?

```
=COUNTIF(B$6:B,B6)<2
```

The above custom formula in Data Validation stops duplicate entries in column B from row 6 downwards, so the rule on the 15th column would be:

```
=COUNTIF(B$6:B,B15)<2
```

Can we do this programmatically in GAS?

Comment: Yes we can. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

The [Data Validation Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) can define a data validation rule across a range:

**Sample Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("B6:B");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied("=COUNTIF(B$6:B,B6)<2").build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

P.S. If you want to reject duplicate values, you can add `.setAllowInvalid(false)` to the rule definition.

Comment: Thank you Carlos M

Comment: Very much appreciated :)